# Apache Spark SQL: Automatic Inner Join?

Tags: join, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

So I have a weird situation.

Whenever I run a sqlContext.sql with a `inner join` statement, I actually get an error but when I read the error, it looks like Spark has already automatically joined my two separate tables once it tries to execute the `on` statement.

Table1:
patient_id, code

Table2:
patient_id, date

```
Select code, date
from Table1
inner join Table2
on Table1.patient_id = Table2.patient_id <- exception shows the table is joined already by this point.
```

Any ideas about this behavior?

Error looks like thisish

`org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'Table2.patient_id' given input columns [patient_id, code, date]`

Comment: could you post the error message as well?

Comment: Update the error message

Comment: could you maybe post the code? we might be able to help you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you have a typo in your program.

However, what you can do is the following:

```
tableOneDF.join(tableTwoDF, tableOneDF("patient_id") === tableTwoDF("patient_id"), "inner").select("code", "date")
```

whereas tableOneDF and tableTwoDF are two dataframes created on top of the two tables.

Just try it out, and see if it still happens.

Comment: Yup I found it, thank you. There's was a slight mismatch of column names, but what a strange error...